# my textfield is returning null even when it has a text, why?

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, textfield

I'm coding a bank program and I want to return the string from one of my textfields, but I'm getting null although there is a text in it!

First I had a `nullPointerException`, but then when I've tried to declare a new variable and gave it the value from the textfield, I got no exception but the new variable got "null" as value!

```
public class FrontEnd extends Application {

     TextField textusr;
     String userid;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #697D8D;");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 500);
        textusr = new TextField();
        textusr.setStyle("-fx-background-radius:10;");
        userid = textusr.getText();        
}
    public String getUserId() {
        return  userid;
    }
```

}

I'm expecting to get the string in that `textusr`, which is the userId, but I'm getting null instead!

Here is my textusr textfield:
[textusr must contain "ii" in this case not "null"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1VAH.png)
Here is a pic of the result:
[image: what im getting is "null"]

Comment: there is no magic: you have to set the text before you can retrieve it :) Instantiating without parameter results in ... null text.

Comment: @kleopatra check the other pic, cuz the user is giving the input for the textfield textusr so it shouldnt be empty!

Comment: The code the OP posted makes no sense. There is a method inside of the start method and the scene is not set. Also, the stage is never shown.

Comment: @Sedrick I've not posted the whole code! My program has 6 classes till now so i cant post all these here! but anyway my question is that i have 2 classes (FrontEnd and Bank) in fronend class i have a textfield with name textusr and this one is getting its input from the user as (username) and the other class (Bank) should take the content of textusr and use it as userid (after editing it...) , BUT im getting null from the textusr eventhough its not empty!

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).